# Manage hundreds of classes without creating and destroying them?

Tags: c#, performance, class, memory

I have a class A that works with hundreds or thousands of classes, each class has a method with some calculations, for example. 
Class A has a method where it choose which class, of those hundreds or thousands, runs. And the method of class A runs many times in a short time.

The solution that I thought at the beginning was to have the classes already created in class A, to avoid having to create and destroy classes every time the event was executed and that the garbage collector consumes CPU. But this class A, as I say, is going to have hundreds or thousands of classes to run and having them all loaded is too high an expense in memory (I think).

My question is, can you think of an optimal way to work with hundreds or thousands of classes, which will run some of them every second, without having to create and destroy it in each execution of the method that works with them?

Edit:

First example: Create and save the classes and then use them, I think it would be a memory expense. But keep the garbage collector from working too much.

```
public class ClassA {

Class1 class1;
Class2 class2;

// ... more classes

Class100 class100;

public ClassA() {
    class1 = new Class1();

    // ... ‎initializations

    class100 = new Class100();
}

public ChooseClass(int numberClass) {

    switch (numberClass) {
        case 1:
            class1.calculate();
            break;
        case 2:
            class2.run();
            break;

            // ... more cases, one for each class

        case 100:
            class100.method();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }   
}
```

}

Second example: Creating the class when used, saves memory but the garbage collector consumes a lot of CPU.

```
public class ClassA {

public ChooseClass(int numberClass) {

    switch (numberClass) {
        case 1:
            Class1 class1 = new Class1();
            class1.calculate();
            break;
        case 2:
            Class2 Class2 = new Class2();
            class2.run();
            break;

            // ... more cases, one for each class

        case 100:
            Class100 class100 = new Class100();
            class100.method();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }   
}
```

}

Comment: As descriptive as this is, i still find it hard to understand the architecture (maybe you can show some code)]

Comment: Any enterprise level application would have huge number of classes and many more number of objects of those classes. And almost all of them are running fine. You need to share more details about what you are trying to achieve and what is the use case where you have one class having large numbers of other classes in it.

Comment: @TheGeneral edited, better?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I'm creating a videogame, that's why it access that class often. It would be very long to go into details, but basically that is what I have explained: a class that uses many other classes depending on a parameter in a method. I have edited with some example codes.

I just want to know the optimal way to approach this.

Comment: Do you really need instantiated classes, could these perhaps be static methods, or is there a lot more to the calculation that needs instantiation and encapsulation?

Comment: "an expense in memory *(I think)*." - this is indication of very low quality post with [tag:performance] tag. You must measure metrics you care about and you must have concrete performance goals for that metric you need to achieve. "I think" is not a way to present performance problem.

Comment: Do make sure to use the right terminology: a Class is a Type and you can create many Instances from it.

Comment: @TheGeneral Hmm, would not a static class be the same (or almost) as instantiate classes in terms of memory? I mean, the code that I put in the first example. I ask because I don't know.

Comment: @TaW I'm sorry if I didn't use the correct terminology, english is not my first language. But creating thousands of instances of classes to work with them when I need would not involve excessive memory expenditure?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I used the performance tag because I believed that we had to use as many tags as possible. My question is a theoretical question, I suppose I expressed myself badly. If you think I should change or remove something, tell me and I'll edit it. I wanted to know, in the example I wrote, which could be theoretically optimal approach.

Comment: _creating thousands of instances.. would not involve excessive memory_ It would only take as much memory as the __fields__ in the instances take. The __methods__ will only exist once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem you face, when you start increasing the number of class instances is that **they all need to be accounted and tracked during garbage collection operation, even if you never free those instances, the garbage collector still needs to track them**.  There comes a point when the program spends more time performing garbage collection than actual work. We experienced this kind of performance problem with a binary search tree that ended up containing several millions of nodes that originally were class instances.

We were able to circumvent this by using `List<T>` of structs rather than classes. (**The memory of a list is backed by an array, and for structs, the garbage collector only needs to track a single reference to this array**). Now, instead of references to a class, we store indices to this list in order to access a desired instance of the struct.

In fact we also faced the problem *(notice newer versions of the .NET framework do away with this limitation)* that the backing array couldn't grow beyond 2GB even under 64-bits, so we split storage on several lists (256) and used a 32 bit index where 8 bits acted as a list selector and the remaining 24 bits served as an index into the list.

Of course it is convenient to build a class that abstracts all these details, and you need to be aware that when modifying the struct, you actually need to copy it to a local instance, modify it and then replace the original struct with a copy of the modified instance, otherwise your changes will occur in a temporal copy of the struct and not be reflected on your data collection. **Also, there is a performance impact, that fortunately is paid-back once the collection is large enough, with extremely fast garbage collection cycles.**

Here is some code (quite old), showing these ideas in place, and **went from a server spending near 100% of CPU time, to around 15%, just by migrating our search tree to this approach.**

```
public class SplitList<T> where T : struct {
      // A virtual list divided into several sublists, removing the 2GB capacity limit 

      private List<T>[] _lists;
      private Queue<int> _free = new Queue<int>();
      private int _maxId = 0;
      private const int _hashingBits = 8;
      private const int _listSelector = 32 - _hashingBits;
      private const int _subIndexMask = (1 << _listSelector) - 1;



      public SplitList() {
         int listCount = 1 << _hashingBits;
         _lists = new List<T>[listCount];
         for( int i = 0; i < listCount; i++ )
            _lists[i] = new List<T>();
      }

      // Access a struct by index
      // Remember that this returns a local copy of the struct, so if changes are to be done, 
      // the local copy must be copied to a local struct,  modify it, and then copy back the changes
      // to the list
      public T this[int idx] {
         get {
            return _lists[(idx >> _listSelector)][idx & _subIndexMask];
         }
         set {
            _lists[idx >> _listSelector][idx & _subIndexMask] = value ;
         }
      }


      // returns an index to a "new" struct inside the collection
      public int New() {

         int result;
         T newElement = new T();

         // are there any free indexes available? 
         if( _free.Count > 0 ) {
            // yes, return a free index and initialize reused struct to default values
            result = _free.Dequeue();
            this[result] = newElement;
         } else {
            // no, grow the capacity
            result = ++_maxId;
            List<T> list = _lists[result >> _listSelector];
            list.Add(newElement);
         }
         return result;
      }

      // free an index and allow the struct slot to be reused.
      public void Free(int idx) {
         _free.Enqueue(idx);
      }

   }
```

Here is a snippet of how our binary tree implementation ended up looking using this `SplitList` backing container class:

```
 public class CLookupTree {

      public struct TreeNode {
         public int HashValue;
         public int LeftIdx;
         public int RightIdx;
         public int firstSpotIdx;
      }


      SplitList<TreeNode> _nodes;

      …

     private int RotateLeft(int idx) {
        // Performs a tree rotation to the left, here you can see how we need
        // to retrieve the struct to a local copy (thisNode), modify it, and 
        // push back the modifications to the node storage list

        // Also note that we are working with indexes rather than references to 
        // the nodes
        TreeNode thisNode = _nodes[idx];
        int result = thisNode.RightIdx;
        TreeNode rightNode = _nodes[result];
        thisNode.RightIdx = rightNode.LeftIdx;
        rightNode.LeftIdx = idx;
        _nodes[idx] = thisNode;
        _nodes[result] = rightNode;
        return result;      
      }
   }
```

Comment: Very interesting and didactic, I have learned a lot. :) Thank you very much for the help!